# OEM 13 Error: Check if all adaptive features parameters are unset

Tags: oracle, oracle-enterprise-manager, oracle21c

I have error when try to install OEM 13.5 on Oracle 21c

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5UuR.png)

> Prerequisite Name = Check if all adaptive features parameters are
> unset
>
> Prerequisite Detailed Name = Check if all adaptive features parameters
> are unset
>
> Prerequisite Status = fail
>
> Prerequisite Recommendation = All adaptive features parameters should
> be unset for improved SQL performance
>
> Prerequisite Detailed Recommendation = If you have set below
> parameters on 18.x, 19.x etc database, you need to reset them by
> running below commands as sysdba:
>
> alter system reset "_optimizer_nlj_hj_adaptive_join" scope=both
> sid='*';
>
> alter system reset "_optimizer_strans_adaptive_pruning" scope=both
> sid='*';
>
> alter system reset "_px_adaptive_dist_method" scope=both sid='*';
>
> alter system reset "_sql_plan_directive_mgmt_control" scope=both
> sid='*';
>
> alter system reset "_optimizer_dsdir_usage_control" scope=both
> sid='*';
>
> alter system reset "_optimizer_use_feedback" scope=both sid='*';
>
> alter system reset "_optimizer_gather_feedback" scope=both sid='*';
>
> alter system reset "_optimizer_performance_feedback" scope=both
> sid='*';

In sqlplus run all alter with sys as sydba but not fix.

Comment: Maybe you need to restart the database for those parameters to take effect?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

you should use these codes:

```
    alter system reset "_optimizer_nlj_hj_adaptive_join" scope=both 
    sid='*';

    alter system reset "_optimizer_strans_adaptive_pruning" scope=both 
    sid='*';

    alter system reset "_px_adaptive_dist_method" scope=both sid='*';

    alter system reset "_sql_plan_directive_mgmt_control" scope=both 
    sid='*';


    alter system reset "_optimizer_dsdir_usage_control" scope=both sid='*';

    alter system reset "_optimizer_use_feedback" scope=both sid='*';

    alter system reset "_optimizer_gather_feedback" scope=both sid='*';

    alter system reset "_optimizer_performance_feedback" scope=both 
    sid='*';
```